# Nested list using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recursion, react-redux

I am trying to create nested lists in separate `div's` using different input data. I am having a problem printing a nested list: `List 2` here. I printing the `name` attribute of object and then checking if there are any `childNodes` print the `name` attribute of those too, nested that is. Here's the `Parent` class.

```
export default class Parent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (

    <div>
      <h4>List 1</h4>
      <ul>
        {this.props.jsonData1.map(item => {
          return <Child name={item.name}/>
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div>
      <h4>List 2</h4>
      <ul>
        {this.props.jsonData2.map(item1 => {
          return <Child name={item1.name}/>
         if(item1.childNodes){
           <ul>
           {item1.jsonData2.map(item2=>{
             return <Child name={item2.name}/>
           })}
         }</ul>
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
    );
  }
}
```

My `Child` class is pretty simple. It only returns a single list element.

```
export default class Child extends Component {
  render() {
    let {name}=this.props;
    return (
      <li>{name}</li>
    );
  }
}
```

I would appreciate some guidance about what I am doing wrong here. I am trying to keep the recursion as simple as possible but apparently I am doing it wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost there, but maybe this will guide you to the right track. Whenever we want to do something recursively, we want to know what our base case would be for us to not call the function again. So in my little example and using what you've got.

```
export default class Child extends Component {
  render() {
    let {name}=this.props;
    return (
      <li>{name}</li>
    );
  }
}
```

Our base case is if `child.childNodes` exist, then we want to create a new `<ul>` element list. However if it doesn't exist but the item exists, then we want to just render the `<li>`. this will keep going until there isn't anymore child nodes or items.

```
export default class Parent extends Component {
  renderChild = (child) => {
    if (child.childNodes) {
      return (
        <ul>
          {child.jsonData.map(item => {
            return this.renderChild(item);
          })}
        </ul>
      ); 
    }
    else if (child.name) {
     return <Child name={child.name}/>; 
    }
    return null;
   }

  render() {
    return (
    <div>
      <h4>Nested Lists</h4>
      <ul>
        {this.renderChild(this.props.jsonData)}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was well explained but I am not getting any list. Is there something that I am not getting?

Comment: I didn't implement your whole solution, but rather the idea and guidance on how to do it. However if you have the full code somewhere I can help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

A few things just looking at the code. In the return for your Parent class, make sure you've encapsulating everything in one div:

```
export default class Parent extends Component {
   render() {
      return(
         <div>
           //other code
         </div>
      );
   }
}
```